# complex tableview with horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a very complex tableview. This is what I should do

1. It should have section headers with a title
2. When you scroll horizontal the whole tableview should scroll horizontal
3. You can not scroll only in one section.

Here is a little screenshot.

[image]

Now the question is, how can I do this?

Comment: I wonder if this is possible with just UITableView. You might need to use UICollectionView for such complex layout.

Comment: If have tried nothing. Spend hours of googling to a fitting solution.

Comment: Surely a UITableView within a UIScrollView is what you're after?  If you don't want the sections to be individually scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not very familiar with `UICollectionViews`, I would try the following:

1.
Create a `UIScrollView`, set its frame to your `backGroundView.frame` and add it to your `backGroundView`

2.
Create your `UITableView`. I guess the content will be dynamic, but it should be possible to calculate the maximum width by simply summing the width of the elements in each section / row.
Make the `tableView.size.width` your calculated width, add the `tableView` to you `scrollView`.

3.
Set the `scrollView.contentsize.width` to your calculated `tableView.size.width`.

If I understood your question correctly, you now should have a `UITablview` that can be scrolled horizontally and vertically. Let me know if it helped.

**EDIT:**

I just created a simple project doing what I described above. 
Until now, the `dataSource` is an array of texts. But it should be no big deal to use an array of e.g. custom UIViews that you add to the `cell.contentViews`.

It seems to work. Feel free to test it:
[Click here](https://github.com/pmkDev/PKComplexTable/tree/master/PKComplexTable)

Comment: @pmk-I'm wondering of the scrollView will catch vertical scroll motions, preventing the tableView from reacting to them.

Comment: I guess this wont be an issue if vertical scrolling is disabled within the scrollView. I will give it a test and update my answer